# Woking With BMP File in C++, Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, g++, bmp

I am trying to work with a bmp file in linux with g++ compiler. I am using C++ language.

I Need to load a .bmp file from the standard input. for example:

```
./a.out < test.bmp
```

So I need a Code to do this job. I think storing the whole .bmp file is good by I don't know how to do this.

I Tried this code but it didn't Work:

```
vector<int> bitmap;
int b;
while ( cin >> b ) {
    bitmap.push_back(b);
    cout << "!" << endl;
}
```

So How should I Do this?

Comment: The major problem is that bitmap files are *binary*, i.e. the data is not structured as text, and the input operator `>>` reads *text* (white-space separated "words" actually).

Comment: `.bmp` is a binary format, use `cin.read()` or another appropriate method to read it.

Comment: Also, while the bitmap file is not structured as text, it *is* structured. You can't just shuffle all data into a vector as plain `int` as not all data is an `int`. You might want to read about [the BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). There are also many libraries available in Linux-based systems that can handle all the loading and saving of many file and container formats, and that can handle the internal structure of the container files and their contained image data. Use them!

Comment: so can you tell me how to read the file from the standard input in binary mode??
The Important part is that the input file is like this:
./a.out < test.bmp

and how can I edit this bmp file after receiving it

Comment: do you have to use stl streams for reading? Why do you not `read(2)` `STDIN_FILENO` or `fread(3)` `stdin` or as mentioned above, `cin.read()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found an answer That Works Correctly.
This Code Reads The bmp_info_header from the *.bmp file from the standard input:

```
char bmpHeader[54];
cin.get(bmpHeader, 54);
```

the "54" in cin.get() tells the system to accept the max 54 numbers from the input and ignores the other.

now for example if we want to find the *.bmp size we should use this code:

```
int filesize = *((int*)(headers + 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> b` reads file in text mode, this is not for binary files. use something like this:

```
 ifstream myFile ("test.bmp", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

to open stream for file, and then

```
if (!myFile.read (buffer, 100)) {
    // do thomething with data in buffer
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have to Use Standard input.
how can I use fstream while i have to give the file in this type:
./a.out < test.bmp

Comment: You can use `./a.out test.bmp` to read name of file through main function parameters. I do not understand why you want to read *.bmp as standard input

Comment: What is your `test.bmp`? Is it image in bmp-format or you just use bmp extention for file of other format? see about BMP here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: It is an image that I want to load it and then, make it black and white

Comment: So why you need it as standard input? What is a source of such strange restriction?